# Any() method fails to compile in Java 1.8 with Mockito 1.10.9

Tags: junit, ant, java-8, mockito

My below code works well with Java 1.7 and Mockito version is 1.10.19.

```
@Test
public void populateUsersEmpty() {

    // arrange
    List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

    // act
    requestBuilder.populateUsers(mxsMessageOutMock, users);

    // assert
    verify(mxsMessageOutMock, times(0)).addRecordSet(CreateNewAlertRequestBuilder.MXS_RECORDSETNAME_USERS);
    verify(mxsMessageOutMock, times(0)).addFieldNewRecord(anyString(), anyString());
    verify(mxsMessageOutMock, times(0)).addField(anyString(), any());

}
```

But when I moved to Java 1.8 with same version of Mockito it started showing below error (bold letters). When I checked Mockito website I found that Mockito 3 yet to support java 8. If yes,then what is solution for this? Should I have to wait for their release or Is there any way to fix this. I tried passing AnyString() in place of any() but my code breaks still. Even anyObject() didn't help me.

verify(mxsMessageOutMock, times(0)).addField(anyString(), **anyString()**);

**CreateNewAlertRequestBuilderTest.java:436:0::0 The method addField(String, String) is ambiguous for the type IMXSMessageOut
[ant:iajc] [error   7]: error at verify(mockMessageOut, times(0)).addField(anyString(), any());**

I understand that Its difficult to suggest without full code but here what I could share piece of code.

Comment: @Eugene, I agree with you but doing so would give me error in my code somewhere else so I am confused how to fix that.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to newest Mockito 2.x.x? It may solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn’t look like a correct cite of the error message. A single method can’t be ambiguous. An error message about ambiguous method( call)s should name the candidates. Besides that, I don’t understand why you posted another method at the end. Are you saying that this source code is part of the error message?

Comment: @Eugene, That worked for me!. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any(String.class)`? if addField is accepting `String, String` why don't u use `anyString(), anyString()`